# Something wrong with ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a simple AJAX request, which sends information to the server, but something goes wrong and i receive only null. Can someone help me with this?

### Source:

```
console.log(data);
console.log(typeof data);
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'script',
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function(){$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();},
    success: function(data){$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();}
});
```

### Logs:

> [2012, 7, 29, 9, 30]
>
> object
>
> Post
>  undefined     undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined
>
> Source code
>  undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=

Comment: What's in your `index.php` that handles the POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
data: data,
```

to

```
data: { "data[]" : data },
```